# Creating queries using JPQL -- Query Syntax Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

When I run the method: `dao.query("SELECT p FROM Profile p WHERE p.group = :id ORDER BY p.datestamp :key", map);` I get the following error:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: : near line 1,
>   column 93 [SELECT p FROM Profile p
>   WHERE p.group = :id ORDER BY
>   p.datestamp :key]

Following is the query method implemenation; anyone see what is wrong?

```
public List<?> query(String criteria, HashMap<String, ?> args) {
        Query sqlQuery = this.em.createQuery(criteria);
        Set<String> keys = args.keySet();
        Iterator<String> iter = keys.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            sqlQuery.setParameter(key, args.get(key));
        }
        return sqlQuery.getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: WHat are you trying to achieve? This code looks completely meaningless now.

Comment: @axtavt: I'm trying to select profiles which have a certain group id and I want to sort the profiles by their datestamp, in `DESC` or `ASC` depending on the `:key` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use parameters to specify sorting direction, because parameter cannot be used in arbitrary places of the query. From JPA spec:

> Input parameters can only be used in the WHERE clause or HAVING clause of a query.

So, in JPA 1.0 you have to build query string with appropriate `ORDER` clause manually.

In JPA 2.0 you can use Criteria API to construct dynamic queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a comma after `ORDER BY p.datestamp` and before `:key`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't quite work. Essentially, I'm trying to achieve this: `SELECT p FROM Profile p WHERE p.group = :id ORDER BY p.datestamp [ASC|DESC]` where the order is determined by the `:key` parameter.